# Bayer Raw for iPhone 14Pro front camera

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode

I am using Xcode to capture depth, video, and PhotoOutput using front camera. It generally works well, but it can only output ProRaw not BayerRaw.

I saw a post online saying BayerRaw is available for front camera of iPhone12.

```
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo
if session.canAddOutput(imageDataOutput) {
            session.addOutput(imageDataOutput)
            imageDataOutput.isAppleProRAWEnabled = true
        }

let rawFormatQuery = {AVCapturePhotoOutput.isBayerRAWPixelFormat($0)}
        guard let rawFormat = imageDataOutput.availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first(where: rawFormatQuery) else {
                    fatalError("No RAW format found.")
                }
```

The code above cannot work. If I change "isBayerRAWPixelFormat" to "isAppleProRawPixelFormat", it works. I also tried to print (availableRawPhotoPixelFormatTypes), it only returns 1 output.

Comment: I have the same issue on my iPhone 13 Pro. 
I'm only able to take a photo in AppleProRaw,
looks like Bayer Raw is not supported